# SwiftUI: image for Multiplatform iOS/MacOS

Tags: swiftui, xcode12

Goal: SwiftUI Image on Multiplatform iOS/MacOS

Problem: when loading Image I need to wrap into an UIImage, and it won't work on macOS

Question: How can I worth with loading images that are Multiplatform?

```
var body: some View {

            Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: image ?? self.image)!)

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a helper file only available to your macOS target that includes this:

```
typealias UIImage = NSImage

extension Image {
  init(uiImage: UIImage) {
        self.init(nsImage: uiImage)
    }
}
```

There are some limitations to this approach, as `UIImage` and `NSImage` don't share all the same methods and initializers, but it will work for basic cases like the one you mentioned in your question (`init(data: )`)

A safer version of this (if you're willing to rewrite some of your UIImage inits) might be to create a custom type eg `MyImage` that is aliased to NSImage on macOS and UIImage on iOS. That way you'll at least have a reminder in your code that you're not actually calling `UIImage` on macOS.